# Maths on the Paris Metro

Tags: chebyshev-polynomials

My brother just saw this on the Paris Metro and asked what it is; unfortunately, it has defeated me.

$$ 
{T_N} ^ {(2)} - {T_{N-1}} ^ {(1)}  = {(LRC)}_{N - \frac{1}{2}},
$$

Does anyone know what it is?  The $T_N$ look a bit like Chebyshev polynomials but what is $LRC$?  Sounds like electrical engineering but are Chebyshev polynomial related to $LRC$ circuits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it with some more searching.

[Global warming equations in the Paris Metro](https://mathematicswithoutapologies.wordpress.com/2016/01/14/global-warming-equations-in-the-paris-metro/)